# What is the best place in Mojolicious where to put content negotiation logic?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

My `Mojolicious` application can respond only by `json` or `html`.

I want to respond with `415 Unsupported Media Type` status code when different format is requested.

```
$c->render( text => 'We support only HTML and JSON',  status => 415 )
```

Which [`hook`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#HOOKS) will be the best place to put this logic to?

**UPD**

```
$c->respond_to(
  json => {template => 'hello', data => $data },
  html => {template => 'hello', data => $data },
  any  => {text => 'We support only HTML and JSON', status => 415}
);
```

The `hello` template is rendered by many actions. And I do not want to `copy/paste` this code snippet among all actions. I prefer:

```
$c->render( 'hello',  data => $data );
```

Which will select automatically one of `hello.json.ep` or `hello.html.ep` template.

I am going to use [`before_routes`](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious#before_routes) hook and `accepts` helper to figure out requested format, but unfortunately it is called for every `static` file. A static response is dispatched already and this will be useless work.

So, is it OK to use `before_routes` hook or there are exists better place to do this?

Comment: Ok, but with this approach, it seems like you would effectively have to slip in Content Negotiation code, outside of where it is being handled.  In short, I'm not sure if your code would actually be more efficient because it would have to check both the request, find and scan the appropriate `respond_to` block to see if it was explicitly handled (Unless you're going to make the kind of assumptions that get hard to unmake as you maintain such a solution).  Efficiency is not just found in the dispatch, but also in its ability to solve your problem without inefficiency.

Comment: @EdwinBuck: sorry, I do not mean speed efficiency. I mean it will be hard to maintain those `copy/paste` code.

Comment: I understand.  To me it seems like you'd be better off with copying / pasting.  Whatever inefficiencies in "code maintenance" you safe will immediately be lost as soon as your framework goes into active maintenance where someone doesn't realize you've effectively rewritten that part of the framework.  It's nice to not fork frameworks, and you are only one find / sed combination away from mass application of the handling code in a way that permits you to configure pages to not have a JSON handler (or to have 3 non-fallback handlers).

Answer (score 1):

To add a response after handling JSON and HTML, add a `any` respond_to handler.  That way it is in the same location as all of the other Accept/Response handling logic.

```
$c->respond_to(
  json => {json => {hello => 'world'}},
  html => {template => 'hello', message => 'world'},
  any  => {text => 'We support only HTML and JSON', status => 415}
);
```

Comment: This is very inefficient to put same code into each action. Also this will disable auto template selection based on `{ format }`

Comment: @EugenKonkov Efficient in what sense?  You didn't benchmark it, and I have no idea what metric you would benchamark (time, memory, response time, etc).  Efficient in the sense of having to type it?  How did you expect to specify it without some typing?

Comment: I have updated the question. I type that in my two templates, there is no need to type those in all ten (hundred?) actions

Comment: I fully understand your reqeust, and hope you find a better solution than mass application using sed / awk; but, it does seem like you are working against the framework in this case.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I do not want to copy/paste this code snippet among all actions. I prefer:
>
> ```
> $c->render( 'hello', data => $data );
> ```
>
> Which will select automatically one of `hello.json.ep` or `hello.html.ep` template.

It sounds like you may need to supplement the behavior of `$c->render`, since the only code your controllers and their actions have in common is framework code.

You could extend [`Mojolicious::Controller`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Controller) creating a `Your::Mojo::Controller` module with a specialised `render_either` (in lack of a better name). In general I'd look at how `render` is implemented, and in particular I'd want to address [the following line](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.71/lib/Mojolicious/Controller.pm#L171) in `render`:

```
my ($output, $format) = $app->renderer->render($self, $args);
```

This `$app->renderer` is a [`Mojolicious::Renderer`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Renderer), and its docs speak of both [`accepts`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Renderer#accepts) and [`template_handler`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Renderer#template_handler):

```
->accepts(..., 'html', 'json')
->template_handler(template => 'foo/bar', format => 'html', ...)
```

A custom Controller could look like:

```
package Your::Mojo::Controller;
use Mojo::Base -base;

sub render_either {
    my $self = shift;
    my $template = shift;
    my $args = {@_};

    # Let the renderer know which formats it should accept.
    # Let the renderer know which template to render in which format.
    # Either call $self->render or reproduce its behavior.
}
```

I've seen examples of both `use Mojo::Base -base;` and `use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller;`. I'm not sure about the implications of picking either.